# how I fetch all countries and shipping states from store? I want to create a shipping calculator

Tags: shopify, calculator, liquid

how I fetch all countries and shipping states from store? I want to create a shipping calculator.

Give me best code and for fetch shipping countries and state from shopify store on cart.liquid if have complete code shipping calculator please share

Comment: Shopify provides JS code for this, you need to check more about `CountryProvinceSelector` it will help you.